# Why are the colours of my VS Code windows' status, menu and title bars different between multiple opened windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

suddenly when I am opening a new folder with VS code, all the bars around are lightblue (see screenshot).
I don't understand why this is happening, since I am using the same Dark Theme.

[image: screenshot of VS Code windows]

Also I tried to change the color for the status bar for example, but then it's only changing in my previous folder and not in any other folder (see same screenshot). How do I fix this? I just want the bars to be the colors, according to the theme that I use.

Comment: Can you share your extension list?

Comment: ambooth.git-rename
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
esbenp.prettier-vscode
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag    
formulahendry.code-runner        
HTMLHint.vscode-htmlhint
mhutchie.git-graph
ms-python.isort
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-toolsai.jupyter
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow
ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
planbcoding.vscode-react-refactor
ritwickdey.LiveServer
voldemortensen.rainbow-tags
whtouche.vscode-js-console-utils
ysemeniuk.emmet-live

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have either one of the following extensions installed and enabled, or something similar to them:

- [`stuart.unique-window-colors`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors)
- [`johnpapa.vscode-peacock`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock)

As for general tips in figuring out if a behaviour is caused by an extension, here's a procedure you can use: Does it happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: When I disable all extensions the bars are still lightblue, unfortunately.

Comment: @lucostz are either of those extensions listed in your list of installed extensions? run `code --list-extensions` in your terminal.