# Weird VS Code Graphical Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

On one machine, running MacOS 14.3 on apple silicon, the activity bar, when put on the side, does not seem to want to sync its theme with the rest of the environment; see the attached picture.[image]

Comment: check if this is due to https://stackoverflow.com/q/76618803/11107541, or whether any of your [settings.json files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) have edited the `workbench.colorCustomizations` setting.

Comment: Nothing in `workbench.colorCustomizations` and the problem is still there when i load into developer mode with extensions disabled.

Comment: do you have the unique window colors or peacock extensions installed?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell

Comment: it stays that colour regardless of what theme you select? have you tried reinstalling VS Code?